# How can I take Input from multiple tkinter listboxes?

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

I have created two Listboxes and I want to be able to take the selection from both of them. Initially, I was only able to take the selection from one but I couldn't select both Listboxes as it would lose the selection, I solved that using `exportselection = False`, however, when I ask for the selection from the `Card_Type` Listbox, it returns the result from the `Player_Name` Listbox. The code for both of the Listboxes are shown below:

```
Player_Name = Listbox(WABOT_U, font=("Rockwell","30"), yscrollcommand = Player_Name_Scroll_Bar.set, justify = CENTER, activestyle = "dotbox")
Player_Name.place(x = 150, y = 590, height = 100, width = 710)

Card_Type = Listbox(WABOT_U, font=("Rockwell","30"), yscrollcommand = Card_Type_Scroll_Bar.set, justify = CENTER, activestyle = "dotbox")
Card_Type.place(x = 150, y = 590, height = 100, width = 710)
Card_Type.config(exportselection = False)
```

This is an example of how I have tried to retrieve the selection from both Listboxes:

```
try:
    Name = Player_Name.selection_get()
except:
    Name = ""
            
try:
    Card = Card_Type.selection_get()
except:
    Card = ""
```

This code returns the Name for both selections. I assume this has something to do with the `exportselection = False`, however, I have no other work around for selection from different Listboxes, so if someone could provide an alternate method of doing that or simply a solution to the problem that would be awesome.

Example Code:

```
def Submit():

    try:
        Name = Player_Name.selection_get()
    except:
        Name = ""

    try:
        Card = Card_Type.selection_get()
    except:
        Card = ""

    print(Name, Card)

Window = Tk()
Window.geometry("1920x1080")
Window.wm_attributes('-fullscreen', 1)

Player_Name_Scroll_Bar = Scrollbar(Window)
Player_Name_Scroll_Bar.pack(side = RIGHT, fill = Y)

Player_Name = Listbox(Window, font=("Rockwell","30"), yscrollcommand = Player_Name_Scroll_Bar.set, justify = CENTER, activestyle = "dotbox")
Player_Name.place(x = 150, y = 590, height = 100, width = 710)

Player_Name_Scroll_Bar.config(command = Player_Name.yview)

Player_Name.insert(0, "Michael")
Player_Name.insert(1, "John")

Card_Type_Scroll_Bar = Scrollbar(Window)
Card_Type_Scroll_Bar.pack(side = RIGHT, fill = Y)

Card_Type = Listbox(Window, font=("Rockwell","30"), yscrollcommand = Card_Type_Scroll_Bar.set, justify = CENTER, activestyle = "dotbox")
Card_Type.place(x = 1060, y = 590, height = 100, width = 710)
Card_Type.config(exportselection = False)

Card_Type_Scroll_Bar.config(command = Card_Type.yview)

Card_Type.insert(0, "Yellow")
Card_Type.insert(1, "Blue")

Submit_Button = Button(Window, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness = 0, text = "Submit", justify=CENTER, command = Submit)
Submit_Button.place(x = 560, y = 900, height = 150, width = 800)
```

Comment: Please provide a complete [mcve]. Also, you should double-check that your exception handling isn't catching something unexpected.

Comment: @BryanOakley I have Included an example, If you run the code and select one Name and one Card it then prints the Name twice.

Answer (score 1):

A program can only have one selection at a time, and `selection_get` will return that one selection regardless of which widget has the selection. In other words, `selection_get` won't return the selection of the widget, it returns the selection owned by the program as a whole.

You should be calling the listbox method `get` and `curselection` to get the currently selected value for each listbox.

```
selection = Player_Name.curselection()
Name = Player_Name.get(selection[0]) if selection else ""

selection = Card_Type.curselection()
Card = Card_Type.get(selection[0]) if selection else ""
```

Comment: Perfect, works great, thank you!